# Join Query to Display info from 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

this is the query to join 2 tables but I keep getting an error message near the JOIN

```
select CHKNBR, pidamt, copied_from_batdat, BATDAT, SEQNBR from UMCDTL 
where copied_from_batdat between '10/11/2013' and '11/4/2013'
and batseq between '001' and '100' and SEQNBR between '01' and '100'
join
UMCFIL on BATDAT=SEQNBR and seqnbr=batadat
```

The output needs to display the

```
Original Claim Number  
Original Paid Amount
Original Check Number
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 'JOIN' specifically, then it needs to be inside of your 'FROM' clause.

```
Select...
From
   table1 JOIN table2 ON Table1.key = Table2.key
Where...
```

If you want to use your 'WHERE' clause to join the tables, then relate the key fields there instead:

```
Select...
FROM
   table1, table2
WHERE
   table1.key = table2.key
   ...
```

Here's a tutorial on using the basic joins if want to understand it a little better: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT CHKNBR, pidamt, copied_from_batdat, BATDAT, SEQNBR 
FROM UMCDTL JOIN UMCFIL ON BATDAT=SEQNBR AND seqnbr=batadat
WHERE copied_from_batdat between '10/11/2013' AND '11/4/2013' 
AND batseq BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
AND SEQNBR BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Comment: its now showing ambiguous column error not sure what that means

Comment: Do you have common field between the two?if yes then try to append tablename. in each of the fields that you select and in your where/join clause.